# program memory usage overflow atmel

Tags: atmelstudio

I don't have much experience with programming besides the basics but i'm programming a sequence of lights to turn on and off when a certain time is reached. However I keep getting program memory usage overflow:

Program Memory Usage :2066 bytes   100.9 % Full (Memory Overflow)
                Data Memory Usage   :   1 bytes   0.8 % Full

can anyone point me in the right direction to what this means and how to deal with it?

Comment: share your code?

Answer (score 2):

you must use PROGMEM

```
#include "avr/pgmspace.h"

const char s[] PROGMEM = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

and read massive

```
a=pgm_read_byte(s+1(or 2,0,1,3,4,5...) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the level of optimization for your code in the project options and optimize for size.

In Atmel Studio select Project -> YourProjectName Properties... -> Toolchain -> Optimization -> Optimization Level: Optimize for size (-Os).

This should reduce your code footprint, however it may have a negative impact on timing, but I assume in your application microseconds are not crucial.

I have not seen your code but I suggest you should rather look into design of your application. For such a simple task the program memory available should be sufficent, especially when less than 1% of RAM is used.